# Alfresco Share 4.2 previewer issues

Tags: flash, share, alfresco, preview

I wonder if something can be done about the 4.2c Share content previewer. It works with some of my PDFs and Office documents, but on others it is broken.

In example, if I load [this](https://www.dropbox.com/s/3ac4ei0g8nnkh6o/broken_preview.png) file, my previewer looks broken, like [this](https://www.dropbox.com/s/3ac4ei0g8nnkh6o/broken_preview.png). The thumbnails in document library look fine, but the preview on document-details page is broken.

I believe I it may be connected issues with PDF files exported from Microsoft Office or Libre Office. I can load some files and preview is rendered correctly, and sometimes it is broken like this. It's always consistent with the same files, though, so I think it has to do something with converters or pdf transformer components or similar. I'm using LibreOffice 3.5 on the server.

Can anybody say if they've had similar issues and how to solve them, or at least point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just encountered this issue on my own installation (maven setup).

It turned out to be a combination of swftools and LibreOffice. I'm not 100% sure which fixed the issue.

I upgraded to LibreOffice 4 (used 3.5 before) and downgraded swftools to 0.9.1 (I used 0.9.2).

It's worth mentioning that I had to reupload the document for the preview to update. I've tried 5 different documents which previously failed and now they look good.

Comment: Thanks, I can try that.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a Open-/Libre Office conversion issue. The preview shows the page pagination preview - so for me it is unexpected but not really broken. Alfresco converts the document into a PDF first using Open/Libre Office and then converts the PDF into a flash object. Maybe you have documents which need other parameters while converting into PDF? How did you install Alfresco 4.2.c (using the installer?) and on which OS?
Your links points only to the same preview intead to the document self.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I got some similar useful responses on Alfresco forums, though not a solution yet. I have 4.2c but checkout a few weeks ago from the SVN, not installer, on linux.